# Is there any way to count non null values of a column and insert into another column such that the count is cumulative?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table like this:

```
    CID|ACC|DRAMT|CRAMT
    1  |001|Null |2000
    2  |002|1900 |Null
    3  |003|100  |Null
    4  |004|200  |Null
    5  |005|Null |200
    6  |006|5000 |Null
    7  |007|Null |5000
```

I need a way to count all the non null value in DRAMT and CRAMT in a cumulative manner.The output i need is like this:

```
    CID|ACC|DRAMT|DRFIN|CRAMT|CRFIN
    1  |001|Null |0    |2000 |1
    2  |002|1900 |1    |Null |1
    3  |003|100  |2    |Null |1
    4  |004|200  |3    |Null |1
    5  |005|Null |3    |200  |2
    6  |006|5000 |4    |Null |2
    7  |007|Null |4    |5000 |3
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try `Sum() Over()`

```
select *, 
   sum(case when CRAMT is not null then 1 else 0 end)over(order by CID) as CRFIN
   from yourtable
```

for older versions you can use `recursive cte/cross apply/correlated sub query`. But if you are using sql server 2012+, then `sum() over()` is the best approach

**Edit :** for older versions

```
;with cte as 
(
SELECT *
FROM   (VALUES (1, 001, NULL, 2000), 
               (2, 002, 1900, NULL), 
               (3, 003, 100, NULL), 
               (4, 004, 200, NULL), 
               (5, 005, NULL, 200), 
               (6, 006, 5000, NULL), 
               (7, 007, NULL, 5000)) tc ( cid, acc, dramt, cramt) 
)
select * 
    from cte a
    cross apply (select Sum(CASE WHEN cramt IS NOT NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) 
                    from cte b 
                    where a.cid >= b.cid) cs (CRFIN)
```

Comment: i am fairly new to this. Can you please clarify on how i can use `recursive cte`, because i used `sum() over()` and it gives me the total sum in all the rows instead of the output column i needed like i mentioned in my question.

Comment: It works as expected. check this : http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/f9019/2/0 Which version of sql server you are using ?

Comment: I am using sql server 2008r2.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using a cumulative count:

```
select CID, ACC, DRAMT,
       count(DRAMT) over (order by CID) as DRFIN,
       CRAMT,
       count(CRAMT) over (order by CID) as CRFIN
from t;
```

This is supported in *all* supported versions of SQL Server.  If you are using an older version, it is time to upgrade.

However, in older versions, you can use correlated subqueries:

```
select t.CID, t.ACC, t.DRAMT, t2.DRFIN, t.CRAMT, t2.CRFIN
from t cross apply
     (select count(DRAMT) as DRFIN, count(CRAMT) as CRFIN
      from t t2
      where t2.CID <= t.CID
     ) t2;
```

Note that `CASE` is not needed in either query, because `COUNT()` does what you want.